# how to generalize the given code for all strings in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, if-statement, generalization

What my aim is that writing a function takes a string as an argument such as "Nisa" and returns "N1I2S3A". But the code that I have written is only works for strings that have only three characters. How do I generalize the code for all strings? If you can help me, I would be really grateful since I am a beginner in python.
Here is the code:

```
tested_str = str(input("Enter a name: "))
def strPattern(mystr):
   while tested_str:
        if len(mystr) == 1:
           return mystr.upper()
        else:
           return (mystr[0] + str("1") + mystr[1:len(mystr) - 1:1].upper() + str("2") 
           + mystr[-1]).upper()

strPattern(mystr=tested_str)
```

Comment: Why did you put a `while` loop there?

Comment: Hint: You need to do something *for every character in the string*.

Comment: @mkrieger1 But how can I do that?

Comment: Have you read the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) already? Do this, and then you will know more.

Answer (score 3):

Here is truly pythonic way:)

```
tested_str = str(input("Enter a name: "))

def str_pattern(mystr):
   return ''.join([f'{c}{i}' for i, c in enumerate(mystr.upper(), 1)])

str_pattern(tested_str)
```

Comment: I doesn't seem to work because your code works like this (nisa --> N1I2S3A4). What my aim is (nisa --> N12S3A)

Comment: @NisaAslan strings are sequences, so if you dont want the last char, you can just use `[:-1]` to take all chars except the last one

Answer (score 0):

- iterate over the characters of the string using [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)

  - start the enumeration at one
- on each iteration: construct a list by appending the character then the *enumeration*
- make a new string by [joining](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) the characters in the list.

Answer (score 0):

This could help I believe.

```
tested_str = str(input("Enter a name: "))
def strPattern(mystr):
    output=[]
    for i,c in enumerate(mystr):
        if i != 0:
            output.append(str(i))
        output.append(c.upper())
    return "".join(output)

print(strPattern(mystr=tested_str))
```

Comment: This should be simple to understand, but I think the previous answer from @scythargon is better (more pythonic) way to do it, you just need to use `[:-1]` to the final string as mentioned in one of the comments.

Comment: Your code is more understandable. Thank you again.